# Routing subnet through proxy to same subnet traffic using iptables, using WiFi Access Point connected to router

Tags: iptables, proxy, routing

I'm having trouble with getting local subnet traffic sent through a proxy. I've got some mobile testing devices on a subnet 192.168.0.0 and a web server on that also. For dev purposes, I need to inject some code. I'm using a proxy to do this. However the traffic that is local to the subnet (i.e. from a device, say 192.168.0.2 to the webserver 192.168.0.3) is not passing through the proxy server. All other requests get the code injected correctly.

My current iptables is configured using the following command:

`iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -p tcp -m tcp -i eth1 --dport 80 -j DNAT --to-destination 192.168.0.1:8080`

Eventually I will limit this rule to source & destination network 192.168.0.0

I'm using an intermediary box (192.168.0.1) with a dumb wifi access point as a router; running ubuntu 12.04.

The proxy is Apache configured as a forward proxy, listening on port 8080.

I know that the traffic is not being sent to the proxy because when I take down Apache proxy the local sites are still served. However any outbound sites are then unavailable.

I don't understand why this rule is not applying to completely local-to-the-subnet traffic.

I there something I am missing? Or is it likely that my WiFi access point, despite being configured NOT to route, is routing this traffic, and thus it never reaches my iptables?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a while I decided that this wasn't possible, and I made sure that the devices and the web server were to be on different subnets, with the proxy server machine routing between the two.